# Magento 2 add new argument in the reference block and get into the phtml

Tags: magento2, blocks, page-layouts, reference

I am working on reference block concept, in that I need to add new arguments and get the argument value on the .phmlt file.

in catalog_product_view.xml I've added the below line of code.

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="current_page" xsi:type="string">detail</argument>
            <argument name="all_page" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
         </arguments> 
         <!-- <action method="setData">
                 <name>current_page</name>
                 <value>detail</value>
                 <name>all_page</name>
                 <value>all</value>
        </action> -->

       <block class="Learn\Test\Block\Sample" name="sample.otherproducts" as="sample.products" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/sample.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Then in my sample.phtml file I am using the following lines for getting the value of the arguments

```
$this->getData('current_page');
$this->getCurrentPage();
```

But nothing is get the value of the current_page arugment, what is the exact procedure to bind the value on reference block layout and get it into the .phtml file

Kindly share your thoughts and ideas, thanks in advance for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add inside sample block:

```
<block class="Learn\Test\Block\Sample" name="sample.otherproducts" as="sample.products" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/sample.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="current_page" xsi:type="string">detail</argument>
        <argument name="all_page" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Now try following way:

```
$block->getData('current_page');
$block->getCurrentPage();
```

**[Update]**

Extend your block by **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View** class. For example:

```
class Learn\Test\Block\Sample extends Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
}
```

Comment: thanks for your update, but as per my requirement I want to add the argument on reference block section, is there has any way to do that?

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: thanks for your support, but I am adding the same sample block also in catalog_category_view, catalogsearch_result_index, catalogsearch_advanced_result.
so that the above procedure is not applicable in my case. if you have any other idea it'll much help me.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned way, it's working

Comment: Then how can I get the parameter values in block(sample.php) file instead of phtml file(sample.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

The block *sample.products* is a child block for the *product.info.addtocart* parent block, so you can call the parent block in the child block (also in the .phtml file) using **getParentBlock()** method

In the phtml you can use the following syntax:

```
$block->getParentBlock()->getData('current_page')
```